# Turn off autosave in vba (Excel/OneDrive)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to turn off the autosave function for my excel document (Excel 365 while saving the file on OneDrive):

[image]

Doing a little research `AutoRecover.Enabled = False` (`Application.`) should be the right attribute but for some reason I can't get it to work. I don't get an error message, but the AutoSave Function does not turn off.

No luck with different objects (`myWorkbook.AutoRecover.Enabled = False`, etc.) either. Any Ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: Try `myWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = False`

Comment: doh...  exactly right...  just found out myself, AutoRecover is s.th. else. Feel free to write an answer, since you were the "first one".

Comment: Thats ok. Feel free to go with @Any1There's answer :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout will do. thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This code checks whether autosave in Excel 365 is on and, if so, turns it off. It displays messages indicating the status before and after the change.

> **Note**: The below code only works for office 365 subscribers and in Excel 2016 or later

```
Sub ChkAutoSv()
Dim AutoSv As Boolean

    If Val(Application.Version) > 15 Then
        AutoSv = ActiveWorkbook.AutoSaveOn
        MsgBox "AutoSave set to: " & AutoSv
        If AutoSv Then ActiveWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = False
        AutoSv = ActiveWorkbook.AutoSaveOn
        MsgBox "AutoSave now set to: " & AutoSv
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This code checks whether autosave in Excel 365 is on and, if so, turns it off. It displays messages indicating the status before and after the change.

Comment: Hope this helps. You should be able to modify it as needed for your code.

Comment: It should be `If val(Application.Version) > 15 Then ThisWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = False` to be honest, not sure why the message boxes are there, or the getter for autosaveon...

Comment: Unless... Can you not set it to false if it's already off?

Answer (score 0):

**Enhancing Any1There Solution**

I just saw the need of reviving this post with an updated answer to create it as a mandatory function whenever you are working with workbooks on O365

```
Sub Exec_Example()
    ...
    Set WBToWorkIn = Workbooks.Open(TxtFilePath): DoEvents
    Call Exec_TurnAutoSave(False,WBToWorkIn)
    ...
End Sub
Sub Exec_TurnAutoSave(IsTurnAutoSaveOn As Boolean, Optional ByVal WBToTurn As Workbook)
If WBToTurn Is Nothing Then Set WBToTurn = ThisWorkbook
Dim IsAutoSaveOn As Boolean
    If Val(WBToTurn.Parent.Version) > 15 Then WBToTurn.AutoSaveOn = IsTurnAutoSaveOn
    Set WBToTurn = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Justification**

With larger deployment of O365, this is usually set on by default, and it seems to crash Excel instance randomly when debugging/on coding execution.The safest path is to turn it off whenever you are dealing with the WB itself in your coding.