# Prevent a workbook being saved to OneDrive with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

I have an Excel macro-enabled workbook that is created from a template. Although the template contains no sensitive data, once the user opens the workbook and is authenticated, some sensitive data is added to the workbook from a remote server. I need to prevent the workbook from being saved anywhere (the vba code communicates with a server to save the needed data).  I can write code on the "before save" event to prevent the workbook from being saved to the local file system, but if an Office 365 user turns on "autosave"  a copy of the workbook will be saved to OneDrive and I can't find a way to prevent this.  By periodically checking the workbook's path, I can notice that the file has been saved to OneDrive, and delete the sensitive data but by then it's too late because the originally saved file will be available in the file's version history.

Any help and suggestions are appreciated.

In response to a question by Cyril below, here is the code on the workbook's before_save event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
  autoSaveOff  ' a sub procedure to turn off autosave
  Cancel = True  ' prevents Excel from saving
  frmMessage.lbllMessage.Caption = "Attempting to save to the Server." 
  frmMessage.Show False
  message_to_addin "save" ' this code cooperates with an Office.js addin to interact with the sercver
  Application.OnTime DateAdd("s", 1, Now), "read_message_from_addin" 
End Sub
```

Comment: If a user doesn't click the button for "enable macros", they can save the file anywhere, regardless of a `before_save` event.  To use an analogy, you cannot prevent water from entering a submarine if the hatch is a screen door.  You may very well want to think of a different way to utilize your data than via Excel.

Comment: Cyril: That is true, but the workbook can't get the sensitive data unless the macros are enabled.

Comment: Then disable autosave, take your existing before_save event, and `if instr(desiredPath, "One Drive") then` don't allow the save?  See [Turn off autosave in vba (Excel/OneDrive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58161421/turn-off-autosave-in-vba-excel-onedrive).

Comment: Thanks Cyril. I already have autosave being turned off when the workbook opens. Unfortunately, the "before save" event does not get triggered when the user initially saves the file to OneDrive by turning on autosave :-(

Comment: Please update your post to include your `before_save` code.

Comment: Loving the screen door analogy @cyril. It's especially fitting for excel because the interface is a grid, and because it's a terrible place to implement data governance and security, although I'm sure we've all done it.